# How to query Partition Table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I was just reading up on partitioned table on BigQuery and couldn't figure out the best practice section. I tried running the following

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `myproject.affiliate.log_20170101`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 * 24 HOUR),DAY)
AND TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),DAY);
```

based on this [documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#best_practices)

But I get this error,

```
Error: Unrecognized name: _PARTITION_TIME;
```

What am I doing wrong? And how is this different from wildcard query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

From below line - i am assuming that you are not actually using partitioned table, but rather sharded table

```
FROM `myproject.affiliate.log_20170101`
```

To deal with sharded table in BigQuery Standard SQL you should use [_TABLE_SUFFIX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix)

> And how is this different from wildcard query?

Sharded table is the set of daily tables which named as tablename_YYYYMMDD and can be queried with use of [Table wildcard functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#tablewildcardfunctions) in Legacy SQL or with _TABLE_SUFFIX in Standard SQL
[Partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) is tone table that internally partitioned by day

Comment: I'm amazed how quickly you noticed that. Yes, the tables-by-date that I thought were partitioned were just sharded tables. I am wondering how different the performance and usability are between the partitioned and sharded tables

Comment: my personal suggestion would be to go with partitioned tables. At a time  - only sharded tables were available so there was no choice. But now - partitioned is the way to go. See more in links provided in my answer

Comment: Yea I read through the articles but they didn't give clear examples on how they are different in performance or usability. The syntax on specifying date range doesn't seem any simpler using partitioned

Comment: Just very high level - Usability wise - huge difference - you do not need to deal with hundreds and hundreds of daily tables flooding your dataset(s). For the same reason performance is expected to be better as listing tables in datasets (which I believe happens internally when you deal with wildcard functions or table_suffix) is relatively expensive

Comment: Partitioned tables do offer better performance (for example, only single metadata lookup is needed for schema), but also don't have some limitations of sharded tables - only 1000 tables are allowed in query, but unlimited number of partitions.